# Detection Form Validation

Tags: php, symfony, craueformflow

I have a **dynamic** form.

For exemple, if something, my form contains FormType1 else my form contains FormType2 or FormType3 ....

I would detect if my form is modify.
If my form is completed, I apply is `valid()` method and if there is an error I return in the form or if there is no error, I apply a redirection.
I know how to do that.

But, **if my fom was submitted without modifications** (with no new value) **I want to apply an other redirection without validation** because my validation will return false with required fields.

I can't test if all values are null because in form there may be combobox or boolean, or initial value, ...

I have a solution with javascript and two submit buttons.
If the value of button submit is 'just_redirection' I don't apply the validation else I apply validation.

**Is there a way** in Symfony2 (or full PHP) **to know if the submitted  form is the same that the initial form?**

Comment: 1. Compare form data to database actual data, see if anything changed

Comment: 2. Put the original data in hidden fields and compare editable fields with hidden fields to see if anything has changed

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thks for your suggestions, those are good ideas. But for each case (form1, form2, ...) I should do apply a specifique code, that I don't want, I just want to know if there is a generic method to know if a form is modified. I I don't have a answer, may be I will code your second solution with a generic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your form is bound with an entity `MyEntity`, in your controller you need to copy your original object, let the form handle the request, then compare your objects:

```
public function aRouteAction(Request $request, MyEntity $myEntity)
{
    $entityFromForm = clone $myEntity;
    // you need to clone your object, because since PHP5 a variable contains a reference to the object, so $entityFromForm = $myEntity wouldn't work

    $form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $entityFromForm);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($entityFromForm == $myEntity) {
        // redirect when no changes
    }

    if($form->isValid()) {
        // redirect when there are changes and form submission is valid
    }
    else {
        // return errors
    }
}
```

For object cloning please refer to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: Thks for your reply. I like this idea, so +1 :). I use the [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle) with modifications, so I will try this to validate

Comment: You're welcome. If it doesn't apply to your use case, please add your form and controller code in your question and leave a comment ;)